# Why is autolinking failing on react-native-zip-archive?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I have an Expo project to which I'm trying to add `react-native-zip-archive`.  I've followed the docs exactly, but autolinking isn’t working on Android (haven’t tried iOS).  I get an error on the package index file, `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNZipArchive.unzip')`.

I suspect there’s something in the package gradle that's to blame, but I don't know enough to debug it.  Anything look off here?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation "net.lingala:zip4j:1.3.3"
}
```

Comment: i faced this issue. did you find the solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately I gave up.

Comment: Did you try any other modules? I'm facing the same issue and unfortunately I can't give up.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution for `null is not an object` error in react-native-zip-archive either. So I ended up writing a Java module and linked it with my react-native project. It is a lot faster and easier to use.

> Save this file as `ZipModule.java` in android/app/src/main/java/com/`YOUR PROJECT`/

```
package com.<YOUR PROJECT>;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.util.Log;

public class ZipModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    ZipModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ZipModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void unzip(String zipFile, String targetDirectory, Callback cb) {
        
        try {
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile)));

            ZipEntry ze;
            int count;
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                File file = new File(targetDirectory, ze.getName());
                File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
                if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs()) {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to ensure directory: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                } finally {
                    fout.close();
                }
            }
            zis.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException err) {
            cb.invoke(err);
        }
        catch(Exception err) {
            cb.invoke(err);
        }
        finally {
            cb.invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

> Save this file as `MyAppPackage.java` in android/app/src/main/java/com/`YOUR PROJECT`/

```
package com.<YOUR PROJECT>;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAppPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new ZipModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

}
```

> And in your `MainApplication.java` in android/app/src/main/java/com/`YOUR PROJECT`/, add your `MyAppPackage` class

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
   @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
   List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
   // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here
   packages.add(new MyAppPackage());
   return packages;
}
```

> And that's it; your native zip extraction module is ready to use. To call it in your JS code, try the following example

```
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";

/* Note: do not destructure ZipModule from NativeModules. It doesn't work that way */
const ZipModule = NativeModules.ZipModule;

ZipModule.unzip(zipFile, targetDir, (err) => {
   if(err) {
   /* Handle the errors here */
      console.error(err);
      return;
   }
   /* Handle What you want to do after file extraction */
})
```

Also remember to rebuild your app (`react-native run-android`) everytime you make changes to the Java class